# Proper way to move an event from the <body> tag to script

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am a java programmer working on a HTML/CSS/JavaScript project.

At the moment, I have the following in my HTML

```
<body onMouseMove='X=event.clientX;MouseMv();'>
```

I am wondering how to take this out of the HTML and place it into my JavaScript. I am not using jQuery for this project.

Please let me know if I should post any of the code from the CSS or JavaScript or if I need clarify or give further details.

Comment: Using inline events is not proper at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.body.onmousemove = function() {
    X = event.clientX;
    MouseMv();
};
```

Comment: Should i just place this anywhere in the JavaScript?

Comment: between script tags on **head** or in a `js` file included in **head** or anywhere wrapped in `window.onload = function () { }`.

Comment: @fardjad Please consider adding description to your answer and clarify how to use it. You can edit your post to include the information given in the comments to assist readers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).onmousemove = function() {
   X=event.clientX;
   MouseMv();
}
```

And remove `onMouseMove='X=event.clientX;MouseMv();'` from your HTML.

Comment: The parentheses around the DOM node reference is odd (and `document.body` should be sufficient in most cases). Will this work no matter where this code falls in the markup?

Comment: @JaredFarrish but sometimes I used to get this weird thing using `document.body` on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to remove it:

```
document.body.removeAttribute("onmousemove");

  or

document.body.onmousemove="";
```

And add it:

```
document.body.setAttribute("onmousemove","doSomething()");

  or

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",doSomething);

  or

document.body.onmousemove="doSomething()";
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I think OP really wants to know how to do it in JS (add the event handler to `document.body`).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to put the code into a function

Place this in between your head tags

```
<script>
    function doSomething()
    {
        X=event.clientX;
        MouseMv();
    }
</script>
```

Then change your body to this

```
<body onmousemove='doSomething();'>
```

Comment: My goal is to have my body tag simply be '<body>'.

Comment: That is the project requirements. The goal for the final product is to have the html contain only information (and ids and classes), styling to be all in a css file and all scripting in a javascript file